# Code Vita: Form the maximum possible time in the HH:MM:SS format using any six of nine given single digits

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge, datetime

**Problem Description**

> The objective is to form the maximum possible time in the HH:MM:SS
>   format using any six of nine given single digits (not necessarily
>   distinct)
>
> Given a set of nine single (not necessarily distinct)
>   digits, say 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, it is possible to form many
>   distinct times in a 24 hour time format HH:MM:SS, such as 17:36:40 or
>   10:30:41 by using each of the digits only once. The objective is to
>   find the maximum possible valid time (00:00:01 to 24:00:00) that can
>   be formed using some six of the nine digits exactly once. In this
>   case, it is 19:48:37.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> A line consisting of a sequence of 9 (not necessarily distinct) single
>   digits (any of 0-9) separated by commas. The sequence will be
>   non-decreasing
>
> **Output**
>
> The maximum possible time in a 24 hour clock (00:00:01 to 24:00:00) in
>   a HH:MM:SS form that can be formed by using some six of the nine given
>   digits (in any order) precisely once each. If no combination of any
>   six digits will form a valid time, the output should be the word
>   Impossible
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Example 1
>
> Input
>
> 0,0,1,1,3,5,6,7,7
>
> Output 17:57:36
>
> Explanation: The maximum valid
>   time in a 24 hour clock that can be formed using some six of the 9
>   digits precisely once is 17:57:36
>
> ---
>
> Example 2
>
> Input
>
> 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3
>
> Output
>
> Impossible
>
> Explanation: No set of six digits from the input may be used to
>   form a valid time.

**The Code:**

```
def bubbleSort(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
            if arr[j] < arr[j+1] :
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]


seq_a=list(map(int,input().split(',')))
# print(seq_a)
bubbleSort(seq_a)
# print(seq_a)

hrs=[None,None]
mins=[None,None]
secs=[None,None]

#hrs
for x in seq_a:
    if x <= 2:
        hrs[0]=x
        seq_a.remove(x)
        break
# print(seq_a)
# print(hrs,mins,secs)

if hrs[0]:
    if hrs[0]==2:
        for x in seq_a:
            if x <= 4:
                hrs[1]=x
                seq_a.remove(x)
                break
    else:   
        for x in seq_a:
            if x <= 9:
                hrs[1]=x
                seq_a.remove(x)
                break
# print(seq_a)
# print(hrs,mins,secs)

#mins
if hrs[1]:
    for x in seq_a:
        if x < 6:
            mins[0]=x
            seq_a.remove(x)
            break
# print(seq_a)
# print(hrs,mins,secs)

if mins[0]:
    for x in seq_a:
        if x <= 9:
            mins[1]=x
            seq_a.remove(x)
            break
# print(seq_a)
# print(hrs,mins,secs)

#secs
if mins[1]:
    for x in seq_a:
        if x < 6:
            secs[0]=x
            seq_a.remove(x)
            break
# print(seq_a)
# print(hrs,mins,secs)

if secs[0]:
    for x in seq_a:
        if x <= 9:
            secs[1]=x
            seq_a.remove(x)
            break
# print(seq_a)
# print(hrs,mins,secs)

if secs[1]:
    print(str(hrs[0])+str(hrs[1])+':'+str(mins[0])+str(mins[1])+':'+str(secs[0])+str(secs[1]))
else:
    print('Impossible')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Bugs

Your program produces these erroneous results:

- `0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,9` → `Impossible` (should be `09:55:55`)
  `0,2,5,5,5,5,5,5,5` → `Impossible` (should be `20:55:55`)

  Due to tests like `if hrs[0]`, `if hrs[1]`, `if mins[1]`, and `if secs[1]`, hours, minutes, or seconds is a multiple of 10, or if the hour starts with `0`.
- `2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,7` → `24:47:44` (should be `22:47:44`)

  The challenge states that `24:00:00` is the upper bound.  The correct answer, `22:47:44`, demonstrates that a **naïve greedy algorithm is not sufficient** to solve this problem.  You might optimistically select `24` for the hour (which would work for input such as `0,0,0,0,2,4,9,9,9`).  However, for the input `2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,7`, you should then find that there is no valid minute if you pick `24` as the hour, and you would **need to backtrack** and try `22` for the hour.

### Algorithm

There is no need to implement `bubbleSort`.  Just call [`sorted(seq_a, reverse=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).  (By [PEP 8 naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#naming-conventions), the function should be named `bubble_sort`.)

Your code is repetitive: you write a similar `for` loop to handle each of the six digits.  You should generalize them to be handled by one loop, which accepts different upper limits for each digit.  Note that you use `<=` tests for most of those loops, but `< 6` for some loops — the inconsistency is confusing.

### Suggested solution

I would define a `placewise_max` function to generalize all of your loops, then call it with three limiting template strings.  Instead of loops with `break` statements, though, I would use [`next()` with a generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2361426/1157100).

Note that there is no need to parse each character as a numeric digit: ASCII comparison will work just as well.

```
def placewise_max(max_template, pool):
    """
    Try to form the lexicographically greatest string from the characters in
    the pool, where the character in each position of the output does not
    exceed the character at the corresponding position in the template.
    Return the empty string if any position cannot be filled.

    >>> placewise_max('91210', list('02301'))
    '31200'
    >>> placewise_max('elmo', 'abcdefghijklm')
    'elmk'
    >>> placewise_max('elmo', 'limo')
    ''
    """
    pool = sorted(pool, reverse=True)
    output = []
    try:
        for t in max_template:
            char = next(c for c in iter(pool) if c <= t)
            pool.remove(char)
            output.append(char)
        return ''.join(output)
    except StopIteration:   # next() failed to pick from the pool
        return ''

def max_time(digits):
    best = max(
        placewise_max('240000', digits),
        placewise_max('235959', digits),
        placewise_max('195959', digits)
    )
    if best and (best != '000000'):
        return '{0}{1}:{2}{3}:{4}{5}'.format(*best)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(max_time(input().split(',')) or 'Impossible')
```

### Educational tips

The solution above uses some rather advanced techniques, and may be overwhelming for a beginner.  However, I would point out an essential next step for improving your coding skills.

It is critical to learn to **write functions**, each with a clearly defined purpose, that accept parameters, return results, and use no global variables.  Document the purpose, parameters, and outputs in a docstring, as I've done.  That will force you to package your code into small, reusable chunks.  For example, can you write a function that accepts a string (or list) of characters, and that returns a tuple with two items — the best possible hour that can be formed from those characters, and all the leftover characters that were not used to form the hour?

Defining a function is necessary to solve this problem correctly, because, as I've pointed out above, a correct solution requires some trial and error.  If you are unable to reuse the code that performs the trials, then you will end up writing if-else statements to handle all of the failure cases, and it's going to be a huge mess!

Comment: To fix the first 2 errors i changed **if hrs[1]** to **if hrs[1]!=None**. Even though **hrs[1]==0** for **2,0,5,5,5,5,5,5,5**  it does not return True thus not satisfying the If condition.

Comment: Is it allowed to make corrections in the above code for the mistakes that you pointed out ?

Comment: No, please don't change the code in the question now. See *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)* for what to do next.

Answer (score 5):

200_success had some great tips for how to make your solution better, however I'd suggest that you use the power of python for your solution. Sure, it won't be as fast as it could be, but if you are looking for speed you can use other languages.

Since we're dealing with permutations of numbers, we can use `itertools` to generate all permutations. And since we're dealing with times, we can use `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.time`.

The idea is simple: let `itertools` generate all permutations of length 6,  and let `datetime` check if they are valid time strings.

```
import itertools
from datetime import datetime

inp = [0,9,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]

form = "%H:%M:%S"
possible = False
max_time = datetime.strptime("00:00:00", form).time()
for perm in itertools.permutations(inp, 6):
    time_string = "%d%d:%d%d:%d%d" % perm
    try:
        time_object = datetime.strptime(time_string, form).time()
        possible = True
        max_time = max(time_object, max_time)
    except: pass

if possible:
    print(max_time)
else:
    print("Impossible")
```

This should pass all test cases since it was literally designed to handle all cases. If it's an interview question they might want you to implement something of your own, but this is the most pythonic way I can think of.